# Errorcode EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xffffffffffffff)

Tags: c, memory, malloc, conways-game-of-life

I have to build the "Game of Life" by J.H. Conway. The game follows strict rules I wanted to implement in my code. Now I am getting an Errorcode anytime I want to debug.
For those who doesn't know the game. Please look it up. It would take some time to explain :)

I was trying to implement the rules for "Game of Life". I started working with dynamic 2D-Arrays. I think I messed something up with my memory allocation, but I can't help myself.

```
// Game of Life

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define EXIT_FAILURE 1
#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#pragma warning (disable: 4996)

int dau_eingabe(int min, int max);
char** zufallsstart(char zeilen, char spalten, float prozent);
void execution(char zeilen, char spalten, char** body);
void print_body(char zeilen, char spalten, char ** body);
void free_speicherplatz(char zeilen, char ** body);

int main(){
    int choice = 0;
    char zeilen = 0;
    char spalten = 0;
    float prozent;
    char ** body;

    srand( time( NULL ) );

    printf("\n");
    printf("\t\t*** Game of Life ***\n\n");
    printf("Zufallsgenerator: 1\n");
    printf("Datei: 2\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Startzustand auswählen:\n");
    choice = dau_eingabe(1,2);
    printf("\n");

    // 1. Menü für Startzustand über eine Datei
    if(choice == 2){
        printf("Datei");
    }

    // 2. Menü für Startzustand: Zufall und Datei
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            // Start durch Zufallsgenerator

                printf("\nGeben Sie die Anzahl an Zeilen an (1 - 255):");
                zeilen = dau_eingabe(1,255);
                printf("\nGeben Sie die Anzahl an Spalten an (1 - 255:");
                spalten = dau_eingabe(1,255);
                printf("\nGeben Sie an, mit wie viel Prozent das Spielfeld mit lebenden Zellen zu füllen ist (0 - 100):");
                prozent = dau_eingabe(0,100);
                

                zufallsstart(zeilen,spalten,prozent);
                break;            
    }

    printf("\nWählen Sie aus die Form der Abarbeitung aus:");
    printf("\n\n1. schrittweise Abarbeitung\n2. animierte Abarbeitung");
    printf("\nEingabe >> ");
    choice = dau_eingabe(1,2);
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
        printf("\n\t\t***Schrittweise Abarbeitung***");
        case 2:
        printf("\n\t\t***Animierte Abarbeitung***\n");
        execution(zeilen,spalten,body);
    }

    free_speicherplatz(zeilen,body);
    return 0;
}

int dau_eingabe(int min, int max){
    int choice;

    if(scanf(" %d",&choice) == 0){
        printf("Die Eingabe ist falsch. Beachten Sie den Eingabebereich!\n");
        choice = dau_eingabe(min,max);
    }

    if(choice < min || choice > max){
        printf("Die Eingabe ist falsch. Beachten Sie den Eingabebereich!\n");
        choice = dau_eingabe(min,max);
        }

    if(choice >= min && choice <= max){
        return choice;
        } 
}

    // Funktion gibt body (Matrix der Zellen) zurück an main-Funktion und realisiert den Zufallsstart
    // d.h. die Funktion erstellt den Startzustand des Spiels
char** zufallsstart(char zeilen, char spalten, float prozent){

    char ** body;
    int maxcells_alive = (zeilen * spalten) * (prozent / 100);
    int maxcells_dead = ((zeilen) * (spalten)) - maxcells_alive;
    int cells_alive = 0;
    int cells_dead = 0;
    char currentstate = ' ';

   
    // Speicherplatz reservieren für die char-Zeiger
    body = malloc(zeilen * sizeof(char *));
    if(body == NULL){
        printf("\nFehler bei der Speichervergabe!\n");
    }

    // Speicherplatz reservieren für die einzelnen Spalten der jeweiligen Zeile i
    for(int i = 0; i < zeilen;i++){
        body[i] = malloc(spalten * sizeof(char *));
            if(body[i] == NULL){
            printf("\nFehler bei der Speichervergabe in Zeile %d!\n",i);
            }
    }

    // Zufallsstart
    for(int i = 0; i < zeilen; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < spalten; j++){
            body[i][j]= ' ';
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < zeilen; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < spalten; j++){
            if( maxcells_alive > cells_alive ){
                if( rand() % 2 == 1){                
                    currentstate = '*';
                    body[i][j] = currentstate;
                    cells_alive++;
                } else if( maxcells_dead > cells_dead) {
                currentstate = ' ';
                body[i][j] = currentstate;
                cells_dead++;
            } else{
                currentstate = '*';
                body[i][j] = currentstate;
                cells_alive++;
            }
        }
    }if(body== NULL){printf("Zellen sind null");}
}
    printf("\n\nStartzustand:\n");
    print_body(zeilen,spalten,body);
                
    return body;
}


    // zeigt die Matrix der Zellen
void print_body(char zeilen, char spalten, char ** body){
    for(int i = 0; i < zeilen; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < spalten; j++){
            printf(" %c",body[i][j]);                       
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

    // gibt den Speicherplatz wieder frei, nachdem das Programm durchgelaufen ist
void free_speicherplatz(char zeilen, char ** body){
    for(int i = 0; i < zeilen; i++){
    free(body[i]);
    }
    free(body);
}

void execution(char zeilen, char spalten, char** body){
    int repetition = 0;
    int dead_neighbor_cell = 0;
    int alive_neighbor_cell = 0;
    char single_cell = ' ';

    // Speicherplatz reservieren für die char-Zeiger
    body = malloc(zeilen * sizeof(char *));
    if(body == NULL){
        printf("\nFehler bei der Speichervergabe!\n");
    }

    // Speicherplatz reservieren für die einzelnen Spalten der jeweiligen Zeile i
    for(int i = 0; i < zeilen;i++){
        body[i] = malloc(spalten * sizeof(char *));
            if(body[i] == NULL){
            printf("\nFehler bei der Speichervergabe in Zeile %d!\n",i);
            }
    }

            while(repetition <= 10){
                for(int i = 0; i < zeilen; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < spalten; j++){                      
    // Spieldynamik
                        dead_neighbor_cell = 0;
                        alive_neighbor_cell = 0;
                        single_cell = body[i][j];

                        if( single_cell == '*'){
                            if( i == 0 && j == 0){
                                if( single_cell == body[i][j+1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell == body[i+1][j]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell == body[i+1][j+1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                            }
                            if( i == 0 && j == (spalten)-1){
                                if( single_cell == body[i][j-1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell == body[i+1][j]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell == body[i+1][j-1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                            }
                            if( i == (zeilen)-1 && j == 0){
                                if( single_cell == body[i-1][j]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell == body[i][j+1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell == body[i-1][j+1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}                               
                            }
                            if( i == (zeilen)-1 && j == (spalten)-1){
                                if( single_cell == body[i-1][j]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell == body[i][j-1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell == body[i-1][j-1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}                               
                            }
                            if( 0 < i < zeilen && 0 < j < spalten){
                                if(single_cell == body[i-1][j-1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell == body[i-1][j]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell == body[i-1][j+1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell == body[i][j-1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell == body[i][j+1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell == body[i+1][j-1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell == body[i+1][j]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell == body[i+1][j+1]){alive_neighbor_cell++;}
                            }
                        }
                        if( single_cell == ' '){
                            if( i == 0 && j == 0){
                                if( single_cell != body[i][j+1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell != body[i+1][j]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell != body[i+1][j+1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                            }
                            if( i == 0 && j == (spalten)-1){
                                if( single_cell != body[i][j-1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell != body[i+1][j]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell != body[i+1][j-1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                            }
                            if( i == (zeilen)-1 && j == 0){
                                if( single_cell != body[i-1][j]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell != body[i][j+1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell != body[i-1][j+1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}                               
                            }
                            if( i == (zeilen)-1 && j == (spalten)-1){
                                if( single_cell != body[i-1][j]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell != body[i][j-1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if( single_cell != body[i-1][j-1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}                               
                            }
                            if( 0 < i < zeilen && 0 < j < spalten){
                                if(single_cell != body[i-1][j-1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell != body[i-1][j]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell != body[i-1][j+1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell != body[i][j-1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell != body[i][j+1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell != body[i+1][j-1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell != body[i+1][j]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                                if(single_cell != body[i+1][j+1]){dead_neighbor_cell++;}
                            }
                        }
                        if(body[i][j] == '*'){
                        if(alive_neighbor_cell != 2 || alive_neighbor_cell != 3){body[i][j] = ' ';}
                        else if (alive_neighbor_cell == 2 || alive_neighbor_cell == 3){body[i][j] = '*';}
                        }else if (body[i][j] == ' ' && dead_neighbor_cell == 3){body[i][j] = '*';}
                        else{body[i][j]= ' ';}
                    }
                }repetition++;
            }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that you could make a more [mre]. E.g. make a demo which used lots of hardcoded initialised variables instea of a menu which can optionally load from a file otherwise definitly add a definition of input to support reproducing your observation.  Also, people might find it easier to understand your code if you translate it to English. Generally please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: For one thing `0 < i < zeilen` isn't how we do range testing in C, and anyway the upper bound is incorrect. it should be `0 < i && i < zeilen-1`

Comment: Aside: why are you using the `char` type for the board dimensions, and not the natural `int`? You used `int` variables to do the iteration, so why not the board dimensions? Also, I don't understand why you are using `float` in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here

```
if( 0 < i < zeilen && 0 < j < spalten){
```

does not do what you think it does. You probably meant to write

```
if (0 < i && i < zeilen - 1 && 0 < j && j < spalten - 1) {
```

Let's see why this is, step by step:

1. C evaluates the highest precedent operators first. In this case, `<` evaluates before `&&`.

   `if ((0 < i < zeilen) && (0 < j < spalten)) {`
2. But if there are multiple operators at the same level of precedence, they evaluate left-to-right.

   `if (((0 < i) < zeilen) && ((0 < j) < spalten)) {`
3. If `i` or `j` are not `0` , the expression does not work.

Let's go step by step (say `i` is `3` and j is `10` for example):

```
if (((0 < 3) < zeilen) && ((0 < 10) < spalten)) {
```

then

```
if (((1) < zeilen) && ((1) < spalten)) {
```

then

```
if ((1) && (1)) {
```

In mathematics, it's common practice to write expressions like `a < x < b`, but the C language cannot evaluate the expression in this way.

Comment: Yes, `0` index is too small when offsetting by `-1` (the algorithm considers neighbours) and `zeilen-1` and `spalten-1` are too large for offsetting by `+1`.

Comment: What's interesting is that the other `if` checks do use `upper_bound - 1` as the border index. Just this one in particular takes a shortcut, and reaches `1` past both the last row and column of the 2D array of `char`s.

Comment: Also, note that this answer assumes `spalten > 1 && zeilen > 1`. The other checks in the code assume each dimension is length 2 or longer, or they'd also be accessing past the 2D array's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The code contains many errors. Some of them have already been mentioned above. In general, this fragment is quite large. I doubt anyone would want to review such a large piece of code. What to do? Some of the errors can be easily found  by compiler warnings / static code analyzer. [Upload](https://godbolt.org/z/KfEhaf19v) the code to Compiler Explorer and check it using the PVS-Studio tool. I give you some code errors’ examples here. But I suppose there are others of a higher-level type.

```
char **body;
....
execution(zeilen,spalten,body);
....
free_speicherplatz(zeilen,body);
```

In fact, the `body` pointer is uninitialized. The `free_speicherplatz` function is supposed to free previously unallocated memory, but works with garbage (uninitialized memory) as a result. Here is the right way:

```
char **body;
execution(zeilen,spalten,&body);
....
void execution(char zeilen, char spalten, char*** body){
  *body = malloc(zeilen * sizeof(char *));
```

By the way, let’s look at the `execution` function, that is below in this fragment. It contains the check that allows you to know whether memory is allocated. This is fine. However, along with issuing a message from the check, it’s better to terminate the program.

Next, look at the following code fragment:

```
int dau_eingabe(int min, int max){
    int choice;

    if(scanf(" %d",&choice) == 0){
        printf("Die Eingabe ist falsch. Beachten Sie den Eingabebereich!\n");
        choice = dau_eingabe(min,max);
    }

    if(choice < min || choice > max){
        printf("Die Eingabe ist falsch. Beachten Sie den Eingabebereich!\n");
        choice = dau_eingabe(min,max);
        }

    if(choice >= min && choice <= max){
        return choice;
        } 
}
```

Only one branch returns a value. In other cases, the [undefined behavior will occur](https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/0917/).

The following expression makes no sense:

```
if(alive_neighbor_cell != 2 || alive_neighbor_cell != 3)
```

The variable is always not equal to 2 or 3. The condition is always met.